# Anchor IDL fails and says unknown account

Tags: anchor, idl

```
anchor idl fetch M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K
```

But I get Error: Account not found, why is this? Surely the Program Account must have an IDL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will return the IDL if and only if the IDL was previously uploaded to the blockchain using `anchor idl init`.

A lot of teams doesnt want to upload their IDL to the blockchain, because that means to "opensource" their program and preffer to work on a more centralized way (a lot of Markets on Solana do this).

Comment: Well. That sucks.